# static_url not resolving correctly, django 1.4

Tags: django, django-contrib

I have an installed app (django_tables2) with its own static files folder but am having issues serving these using `{{ STATIC_URL }}`.  After reading the django docs, if I run

```
>>> python manage.py findstatic django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css
```

findstatic indeed correctly locates the one matching file within the apps directory of site-packages.

My template for the page in question contains:

```
{% block extrahead %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

And related blocks exist in the parent template.

This page is served at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/product_groups/Analytical/`.  However, when running the development server I get a 404 for the css as its pointing to the wrong location:

```
GET /todo product_groups/Analytical/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css HTTP/1.1 404 2942
```

What's going on and why isn't the server following `{{ STATIC_URL }}` the same way as findstatic?  I had this same static_url css working before doing some url redesigns, but can't seem to make it work in the new design.  Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

*Relevant snippets from settings.py:*

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/riedldar/Documents/Code/Arclin/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "C:/users/riedldar/Documents/Code/Arclin/Arclin/static",
)
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
....
'django.contrib.staticfiles',)

# Required for tables2
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
# 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

*from urls.py:*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'Arclin.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^Arclin/', include('Arclin.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

# Todo/Task manager
url(r'^todo/', include('todo.urls')),

# Login/out
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'Arclin.views.logout_page'),

# User Homepage
url(r'^$', 'todo.views.user_home'),

# 
)
```

*and todo\urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
#from models import ProductGroup

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^product_groups/([\w-]+)/$', 'todo.views.items_by_product_group'),
    url(r'^task/(?P<task_id>\d{1,6})$', 'todo.views.view_task',  name='todo_task_detail')
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `todo.views.items_by_product_group` rendering your template with [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext), or one of the [shortcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/) or generic views that include it? If not, your template context processors won't be applied to add variables like `STATIC_URL` to your page context, resulting in the behavior you're describing.

As an aside, Django 1.4 introduces a new [`{% static  '…' %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag) template tag, which lets you refer to static files without needing `STATIC_URL` from the context. Using that should also prevent this problem (but you'll probably still want to investigate if or why RequestContext is missing: that's usually a bug).

Comment: Thanks Piet.  You nailed it.  I modified my todo.views.items_by_product_group when changing around the url's and switched from a generic view to a regular view function.

Comment: As explained in your link, I had to add `context_instance = RequestContext(request))` as an argument to render_to_response and once I did that the `STATIC_URL` is being utilized.  Final return statement: `return render_to_response('items_by_product_group.html', {'incomplete_table' : incomplete_table , 'completed_table' : completed_table}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`.  Will have a look at 1.4's new template tag.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can use a further shortcut for that: `render(request, template, data)`. That does the same as `render_to_response(template, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`.